# Manipulating Pivot Table Data with Macro

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a survey that I completed at work and want to create a data dashboard for it with a slicer so that users can manipulate a number of graphs on the dashboard. In my real survey, I have over 50 questions and want to create a pivot table and corresponding graph for each table (let's just say pie chart for now, I can change that later).

In this example document, I have replicated what the survey looks like with limited (and fake) data. My issue is, the macro never successfully acts upon the next pivot table, always taking info from the first pivot table. This is likely due to the "=GETPIVOTDATA" formula that requires the title of the pivot table for the formula.

My goal for the macro is to take the pivot table (or make it would be even better), copy the data onto the side (but in a way that will allow the slicer to properly filter it), and then create a chart and then cut and paste that chart onto the dashboard tab.

Here is the link to the example document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvAzkXES5QuNnjo99j3W90yA4R2ZWLTu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110216188708141241031&rtpof=true&sd=true

Here is the Macro I am using:

```
Sub Creating_Graph()

Creating_Graph Macro



Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-6]"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =         
"=GETPIVOTDATA(""Company"",R2C1,""Q1"",1)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=GETPIVOTDATA(""Company"",R2C1,""Q1"",2)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=GETPIVOTDATA(""Company"",R2C1,""Q1"",3)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1:C1").Select
ActiveCell.Activate
Selection.Style = "Percent"
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Pivot 
Table'!$H$4:$J$4")
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 137
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -94
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 
1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -9).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (2)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.Paste
ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (7)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Question 1"
ActiveCell.Offset(16, 9).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementLeft 572
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementTop -24
End Sub
```

To explain in more detail. In my example, I have three questions and multiple different companies. The goal is to make a pivot table per question (company on row and question answers (1-4) on column). Then the goal is to create a pie chart based off of the grand totals of that table so that it will change when a slicer is made and the companies are specifically chosen. When a specific company is chosen, then the pie chart changes accordingly.

I can do all of this, but have been trying to create the above Macro to do it for me, as I have 50+ questions to go through. The issue with the Macro is that the "GETPIVOTDATA" always pulls from the same pivot table, and I can't figure out how to make a formula that allows it to take from the pivot table next to my reference cell.

Comment: You mention a macro in your question - could you share what you have tried so far in the body of your question? Myself and others will not download your file and the question should include all relevant info. You may want to split this into multiple questions based on the number of different goals you specify.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy thank you. I've added more info above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample data to play with (I don't have your data):

```
Empl    Date    Qty DateX   QtyX
D Meb   08/06/07    43  Date1   Qty1
A Hef   05/28/07    56  Date1   Qty1
D Meb   09/21/07    67  Date2   Qty2
A Hef   01/16/08    41  Date2   Qty2
A Dug   08/17/07    60  Date1   Qty1
U Ues   02/14/08    90  Date1   Qty1
A Dug   06/27/07    34  Date2   Qty2
J Fet   12/13/07    43  Date1   Qty1
A Dug   01/20/08    18  Date3   Qty3
A Hef   08/04/07    18  Date3   Qty3
A Uaj   09/15/07    13  Date1   Qty1
P Lon   08/31/07    64  Date1   Qty1
B Fad   11/27/07    75  Date1   Qty1
A Dug   11/20/07    13  Date4   Qty4
B Fad   10/22/07    18  Date2   Qty2
B Fad   12/06/07    54  Date3   Qty3
A Uaj   10/15/07    98  Date2   Qty2
E Sar   11/29/07    78  Date1   Qty1
U Ues   07/09/07    80  Date2   Qty2
U Ues   07/18/07    75  Date3   Qty3
A Uaj   12/04/07    72  Date3   Qty3
D Meb   11/04/07    89  Date3   Qty3
Q Nik   10/13/07    52  Date1   Qty1
A Hef   02/01/08    84  Date4   Qty4
B Fan   09/17/07    91  Date1   Qty1
B Fan   05/31/07    20  Date2   Qty2
B Fad   11/05/07    32  Date4   Qty4
F Cat   10/17/07    71  Date1   Qty1
Q Nik   11/03/07    91  Date2   Qty2
A Uaj   09/30/07    26  Date4   Qty4
B Fan   01/31/08    54  Date3   Qty3
```

I turned on the Macro Recorder and got this:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R2C2:R33C6", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion10
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Qty"), "Sum of Qty", xlSum
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Empl")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("QtyX")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("A4:E16").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$A$3:$F$17")
    
End Sub
```

Here's the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've added more info above. Hopefully that helps.